# How to plot quadriellipse?

Tags: plotting

[image: quadrellipse]

The central red curve defined by 4 points in the diagram above is called a "[quadriellipse](http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/multiellipse/multiellipse.shtml)" (not sure).
How do I plot it in *Mathematica*?

Comment: what have you tried? Do you know anything about the mathematics of the figure you've shown?

Comment: I tried to find there are blue,pink,green, yellow 4 Cardioid.

Comment: Where did you get this picture from?

Comment: @J.M.[from this link](http://www.mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/multiellipse/multiellipse.shtml)

Comment: Next time, please include the sources of any image you are using that you did not generate yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Converting the multipolar equation in the link into Cartesian form, here is a $4$-ellipse where the four foci are arranged in a square:

```
With[{pts = CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 4], d = 24/5 (* sum of distances *)}, 
     ContourPlot[Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, pt], {pt, pts}] == d,
                 {x, -3/2, 3/2}, {y, -3/2, 3/2}, 
                 Epilog -> {Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]], Point[pts]}]]
```

[image: 4-ellipse]

This is only a portion of the full Cartesian curve; to see the full curve, we can use `GroebnerBasis[]` to obtain the rationalized Cartesian equation:

```
With[{d = 24/5}, 
     ContourPlot[First[GroebnerBasis[Sum[Sqrt[#.#] &[{x, y} - pt],
                                         {pt, CirclePoints[{1, 0}, 4]}] - d,
                                     {x, y}]] == 0 // Evaluate,
                 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 105]]
```

[image: the full curve]

---

It was simple enough to make a `Manipulate[]` for playing with general $n$-ellipses, so I made one:

```
Manipulate[ContourPlot[Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, pt], {pt, pts}] == d,
                       {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}],
           {{d, 5}, 0, 20}, {{pts, N[CirclePoints[4]]}, Locator, LocatorAutoCreate -> All}]
```

[image: n-ellipse generator]